# passing the value of my data from database in ajax w/ codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem related on passing my data came from database to another function in jquery. I want to pass two of my data from the loop of my ajax from database on a button click function. My problem is, when i go pass the value , instead of the true value of my check_up_id = 1-0/1-1, when i passed it to other function and alert it or output it, it becomes only 0 and 1. I tried to console.log the value but i don't know why it gives me a wrong value.

Please take a look in this code inside my for loop from the first function:

```
<button onclick="add_bill('+data[i]['check_up_id']+','+data[i]['patient_id']+')
```

Here is my code:

```
function show_finished_check_up() {
$("#bill_queue").empty();
$.ajax({
    url: siteurl+"billing/bill_list",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
      if(data.length>0) {
        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
          $("#bill_queue").append('<div class="col-sm-10">'+'<div class="panel-group">'+'<div class="panel panel-info">'+'<div class="panel-heading">'
                                   +'<h4>'+data[i]['check_up_id']+' '+data[i]['patient_lname']+', '+data[i]['patient_fname']+' <button onclick="add_bill('+data[i]['check_up_id']+','+data[i]['patient_id']+')" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Add bill</button></h4>'
                                   +'</div><!-- panel-heading -->'+'</div><!-- panel -->'+'</div><!-- panel-group -->'+'</div><!-- col-sm-10 -->');
          console.log(data[i]['check_up_id']);       
        };
     }   
   });
}

function add_bill(check_up_id, patient_id) {
  $('#add_bill').modal('show');
//  $('.modal-body #patient_id').val(patient_id);
//  $('.modal-body #check_up_id').val(check_up_id);

  alert(check_up_id);
  alert(patient_id);
}
```

now the problem, when i passed it from `add_bill` function the patient_id returns a true value but my check_up_id value returns only 0 instead of 1-0
I also already put a console.log below the loop and when i saw the value from database it gives me 1-0, now when i passed it from the function `add_bill` it gives me 0 value instead of 1-0.

Comment: @AdrienLeber thank you for your reply. Here it is 
<button onclick="add_bill(\"'+data[i]['check_up_id']+'\",\"'+data[i]‌​['patient_id']+'\")" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right">

it gives me error sir

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces this. See [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl all i did was passing the variable . then the variable changed. Thats it.

Comment: So copy that to a reproduce-able demo. We have no way to reproduce it ourselves from what is shown

Comment: @charlietfl thats all of my code sir. :'( ?

Comment: But you have access to the html source in the browser that we don't. Use browser dev tools to get at it